# Publishing PostGIS Rasters to GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I am attempting to publish PostGIS rasters to GeoServer, but am having difficulty figuring out the correct way to do that.  I am a newbie (< 100 hrs) -- Could point me in the right direction?

I have installed GeoServer 2.20.4, along with PostgreSQL 13.7 and PostGIS 3.2.1.  I was able to successfully publish raster data to GeoServer from my machine to ensure that it was working, but I've been having trouble publishing from PostGIS.

I am attempting to follow the directions from the GeoServer site: [PGRaster](https://docs.geoserver.org/2.20.x/en/user/community/pgraster/pgraster.html), but after downloading the PGRaster plugin: [plugin](https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.20.x/community-latest/), and unzipping the .jar file into /usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib, GeoServer stops running in the browser.

This is the error I get when trying to run the UI in a browser window:
[image]

From the Geoserver log:

"2022-05-28 16:56:55,519 WARN [support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pgrasterCoverageStorePanel' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-pgraster-2.20-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class' for property 'factoryClass'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.ImageMosaicJDBCFormat]
2022-05-28 16:56:55,520 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - destroy() invoked
"

GeoServer runs if I remove the gs-pgraster-2.20-SNAPSHOT.jar file from the WEB-INF/lib directory.  I'm wondering if the problem is the version of PostGIS?  The GeoServer instructions mention using a PostGIS 2.0 database, so is the issue that I have PostGIS 3 installed?

If so how would I go about uninstalling PostGIS 3 without getting myself in a tangle?

Comment: I was able to get the GeoServer running.  The issue was I needed the JDBC Image Mosaic plugin as well.  It was not found in the most recent versions of GeoServer on the site, I had to go back to GeoServer 2.17 page to find it under coverage formats.  Still have to see if the plugin will work with GeoServer 2.20 but I do see the option for ImageMosaicJDBC available on the UI.

Comment: The ImageMosaicJDBC plugin has been completely removed from the GeoServer source code, due to lack of a maintainer. If the PGRaster community module is not working either, we should remove it as well. If you're up for contributing a patch, this line of code https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/main/src/community/pgraster/src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml#L11 should probably state "org.geotools.gce.pgraster.PGRasterFormat" instead. Something for you to try out,  if it works, make a pull request to fix that line.